# When i run automated script it is not give me any error but, button is not click

Tags: eclipse, selenium

With using TestNg Plugin, Button is not clickable.
I attached inspect details of that button.

```
@Test(priority = 1)
public void Cartlogin() throws Exception{

    driver.get("https://rxvaletapi.com/rxnew/medication/30006/709-ANASTROZOLE");
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    WebElement home = driver.findElement(By.className("c-radio-btn"));
    home.click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    WebElement addcart = driver.findElement(By.id("addToCartHome"));
    addcart.click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    // This confirm button is not clickable.
    WebElement conf = driver.findElement(By.className("bg-primary1"));
    System.out.println(conf);
    conf.click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);

}
```

Inspect of that button:

```html
<button type="button" class="bg-primary1 text-white text-white-hov op-90-hov brdr-rad-4 text-white py-2 px-3" onclick="addCartValue(2)" data-dismiss="modal">Confirm</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
WebElement conf = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[contains(@class,'bg-primary1')])[26]"));
conf.click();
```

Comment: <button type="button" class="bg-primary1 text-white text-white-hov op-90-hov brdr-rad-4 text-white py-2 px-3" onclick="addCartValue(2)" data-dismiss="modal">Confirm</button>

Comment: // This confirm button is not clickable.
        WebElement conf = driver.findElement(By.className("bg-primary1"));
        System.out.println(conf);
        conf.click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

Comment: What is the meaning of [26] ? Why it is used ?

Comment: Many locator with class name contains `bg-primary1`. so it's [26] as count the the locator

Comment: maybe you mean 25th by index ? 26 by count

Comment: 24th by index and 25th by count